# How do I push two libraries in the same project in jitpack.io using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, jitpack

I know how to push a library to jitpack using Android Studio.

For a single library module,

***Step 1:*** I apply this plugin to project level build.gradle,

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
```

***Step 2:*** In library module's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
group='com.github.username'
```

I have two library modules in my project, A and B.
B depends on A.

**What I want to achieve is push both A and B to jitpack as a single gradle dependency, and provide user a choice to use either A or B.
I suppose they can achieve it with something like exclude in build.gradle, right ?**

Now, given I have two library modules A and B, do I follow ***step 2***  for both the library module ?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a too old thread. Maybe this answer helps someone.

Take a look at repo

https://github.com/Gokuldroid/Lily/blob/master/app/build.gradle

I have three modules lilycore , lilypref , lilytoast. and lilypref and lilytoast depends on lilycore. I hope that's what you need.

Just add

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
group='com.github.username'
```

in all library modules and use those libraries in your app by using

```
compile 'com.github.username.RepoName:Module-1:master-SNAPSHOT'
compile 'com.github.username.RepoName:Module-2:master-SNAPSHOT'
compile 'com.github.username.RepoName:Module-3:master-SNAPSHOT'
```